# HighCharts title styles i.e textDecoration property not applying when we export the chart using canvg

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working on Highcharts examples, I have applied some styles to the title property it is showing correctly in the browser, but when we try to export the chart using canvg some styles i.e **text-decoration** style not applying.

```
title: {
        text: 'Client-Side Download Example',
         style: {
            color: '#FF00FF',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            textDecoration: 'line-through'
        },
      useHTML: true
    },
```

Here is the example link to understand the issue http://jsfiddle.net/sairampotta/cLrwvtd1/2/

Please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Highcharts exporting module for it, which supports this functionality.

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    chart.exportChart();
})
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g134hum2/

Comment: For High-resolution purposes, we used canvg, instead of  "chart.exportChart()".

Comment: I am not able to help you with using the third part libraries.